# assistance needed to recognize the format of my file.txt

Tags: encryption, format

I work automating molecular biology protocols in a lab using specialized equipment. Usually, they have an API to refer or you can hard code some protocols. We purchased a machine from China which protocols are written in this format:

```
u4Msx0GL/n+bJqjOe9MjEYwBH2cdx53USFAc5k7zPr0=
NhDE87R3vp5ZOlH4YvgxCd7fATjhdtsgRRH79aRLxHCMnXf/yiXKaHAta6/WGaVT
XSTaUbFECD+DbnmV2F15Qr0e+HiupoaSJ6cAl9tIdYc=
H5vDtJjJsBMhp8quo1CrA+yVMw/faKsGnFIlB1iyUFwS5uFfaJRGfuMHfxnLxt1Y
cDD0Q6ceo7CeUvV1qs1npnwiHOxCWKOM3ZF6xJ49FeFETaVDMxMgk9rij0Id4NNg
IlDSqu7GppHxHQpFmVfIkfC6JIA/1so0ayu8LN6jsDEgfIxJOTrhyRtX7XXZ4GAE
uGNr/9XKtMdCmI4hGlIDQufkIxI4zjtnptbsLHweTBuZPz7TJlJ3pZh/of4Xovuw
sLfR+KbO2u6U+BQZ0x97ilh4JlnO4rKw7mRGJq9GFZc0BPjQKJ014KL2TzJDLf+y
```

I don't know if this is an encrypted format or how I can handle it.

Every protocol is in the same format and has the same structure. they are transferable between machines. I have tried to identify what it is without succeeding.

Comment: What are you expecting the result to look like? Without that, it will be pretty much impossible for anyone to know if they succeeded. For example, It looks a little like lines of base64-encoded data, so I decoded the first line & got some binary data -- is it correct? I have no way of knowing. Realistically, your best course of action is to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: the machine controls temperature, time, and movement on one axis.
e.g.  20 seconds in position 1 at 60 degrees... But yes, I think it's a hard quest